# Where in windows registry the console width is stored?

Tags: console, windows-xp, registry, width

My default console width is 80, but when I look into `HKCU\Console` there isn't a name that has this value. Only one that has supposedly to do with with is: `WindowSize` but it has value of 0x190050, that is dec: 1638480. Do the last two digits of it represent value I'm searching for ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In HKCU\Console

0x19 = 25
0x50 = 80
So this is 25x80

In decimal, it's rows times 65,536 plus columns. `(25 * 65536) + 80 = 1638480`

Documentation is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978585.aspx).