# Problems with the console in Visual studio 2019 windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console

I have a problem with the console in Visual studio that I could not find a solution to for a very long time. Anytime I run a program in VS, the default console size is pretty small (I went in the options to resize it to a larger console but that never worked). Furthermore, the output doesn't show unless I put system("pause") before the printing lines and sometimes it even disappears for a milisecond after showing. [example of a simple "hello world" program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSrJC.png)

I tried reinstalling VS, no effect. 
PS. I will give a further detail that I think might be important. A few months ago after starting my PC and typing in the password, I had a black screen and a console opened. I couldnt access anything unless I typed "explorer" in the console, then all my icons and stuff loaded on the screen.I have to type in "explorer" in the console every time I start my PC now. The console in Visual studio problem has occured since then.
Sorry for the messy explanation, thanks in advance

Edit: Adding a video to give you a better idea of what happens. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLCv1rykj_0&feature=youtu.be

Comment: How big is the console window if you open a console using `<WindowsKey>+R` and then enter `cmd.exe`?

Comment: The same size as in VS. The biggest problem although is the behaviour, it behaves differently for different programs.

Comment: Odd. What if you change the properties of it. Does it stick?

Comment: The new properties get reset back to the small dimensions after I close it.

Comment: That depends on how you set them. Press `<shift>` + right click the command window on the taskbar. Change the properties and then they _should_ stick.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. Should I consider reinstalling the windows?

Comment: That sounds drastical. I'd keep on searching. Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664039/where-in-windows-registry-the-console-width-is-stored) can help. Did you change the properties via the `Default` menu option?

Comment: Yes, I changed the default.

Comment: Ok, then I'd go into the registry as described in the link and try it that way.

Comment: I just did this, changed it from the registry, but there seems to have no effect either. The defaults get changed after I did it from the registry, but it still opens the small window every time I run it.

Comment: Utterly weird. I have no idea what the cause could be.

Comment: Thanks for all the input!

Comment: **"sometimes it even disappears for a milisecond after showing."** I suggest you could try to go to Tools/Options/Debugging/General to enable “Automatically close the console when…..” If this issue is not solved, as far as I'm concerned you may need to re-install your system.

Comment: The console doesn't get closed, just the output dissapears from it.

Answer (score -1):

change your code like below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   cout <<"hello world";
   return 0;
```

Comment: Did it, no success, it still does not show the output.

Comment: Reasons for my downvote: 1) This does not address OP:s problem at all. 2) Actually recommending people to do `using namespace std;` is terrible advice. It's the counter-advice you'd typically get from anyone who's used C++ for some time.